# Underscore methods to ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

can someone look at this and make sense out of how to turn this into native JS.

```
_.chain(polls).deepClone().indexBy("id").value()
```

I tried to look up `deepClone` and was unable to find out where it comes from. This is code that I have taken over and don't have much familiarity with it. Thanks for help.

Here is a working example that I have:

```
function loadPolls () {
    return ScheduledEventService.getPolls($scope.webcastId)
        .then(function(polls){
            $scope.originalPolls = _.chain(polls).deepClone().indexBy("id").value();
            $scope.webcast.polls = polls;

            _.each(polls, function(poll){
                poll.answers = _.map(_.range(Polls.MaxAnswers), function(i){
                    return (poll.answers && poll.answers[i]) || {};
                });

                poll.readOnly = poll.status !== "Closed" || poll.totalResponses > 0;
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Ouch on the -1. Reason for that?

Comment: can you provide working example?

Comment: @PratikParekh - I hope what I have added helps

Comment: Sorry found out that this was an internal helper and had been deleted - `deepClone`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `deepClone` nor `indexBy` (from Underscore) have direct native equivalents.

`indexBy` is easy enough:

```
function indexBy(object, key) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce(result, k) {
    const value = object[k];
    result[value[key]] = value;
    return result;
  });
}
```

This uses `reduce` to walk through the input object (actually, walk through its keys), and build up a `result` object whose keys are the values of the `id` property on each sub-object, and whose values are the sub-objects themselves, just like `_.indexBy` does.

`deepClone` you will have to find some version of. There are many here on SO.

Once you have those, your logic is simply

```
indexBy(deepClone(polls), 'id')
```

If only one level of deep-cloning is required, you could change the line above to

```
result[value[key]] = Object.assign({}, value);
```

and then just do

```
indexBy(polls, 'id')
```